# CSS help needed

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, user-interface

I need help in Stylesheet. I have a div which has:

```
Header text with underline, 
icon
link but
```

ton with description text.

All are separate controls.

'1' in image attached is the UI which I am currently getting and '2' is what I want.

The second module gets generated dynamically and overrides the text of first div. Which property can be used to fix this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `clear:both` to the CSS for the heading `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Nicolas Gallagher's clearfix hack for cross-browser support back to IE6:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Here's the code:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

/**
  * For IE 6/7 only
  * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
*/
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Apply the `cf` class to your first `div`.